# msgraph-sdk-python not returning any data

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I took reference from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python-app-only?tabs=aad.

Copied and pasted the exact code but it is not returning list of users. It is returning access token though.

### ****main.py file****:-

```
import asyncio
import configparser
from msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error import ODataError
from graph import Graph

async def main():
    print('Python Graph App-Only Tutorial\n')

    # Load settings
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(['config.cfg', 'config.dev.cfg'])
    azure_settings = config['azure']

    graph: Graph = Graph(azure_settings)

    choice = -1

    while choice != 0:
        print('Please choose one of the following options:')
        print('0. Exit')
        print('1. Display access token')
        print('2. List users')
        print('3. Me')

        try:
            choice = int(input())
        except ValueError:
            choice = -1

        try:
            if choice == 0:
                print('Goodbye...')
            elif choice == 1:
                await display_access_token(graph)
            elif choice == 2:
                await list_users(graph)
            elif choice == 3:
                await mee(graph)
            else:
                print('Invalid choice!\n')
        except ODataError as odata_error:
            print('Error:')
            if odata_error.error:
                print(odata_error.error.code, odata_error.error.message)

async def display_access_token(graph: Graph):
    token = await graph.get_app_only_token()
    print('App-only token:', token, '\n')

async def list_users(graph: Graph):
    users_page = await graph.get_users()
    print(users_page)

    # Output each users's details
    if users_page and users_page.value:
        for user in users_page.value:
            print('User:', user.display_name)
            print('  ID:', user.id)
            print('  Email:', user.mail)

        # If @odata.nextLink is present
        more_available = users_page.odata_next_link is not None
        print('\nMore users available?', more_available, '\n')


async def mee(graph: Graph):
    user = await graph.me()

async def make_graph_call(graph: Graph):
    # TODO
    return

# Run main
asyncio.run(main())
```

### **---------------------------------------------------------------------------
****graph.py file****:-

```
from configparser import SectionProxy
from azure.identity.aio import ClientSecretCredential
from kiota_authentication_azure.azure_identity_authentication_provider import (
    AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider
)
from msgraph import GraphRequestAdapter, GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.users.users_request_builder import UsersRequestBuilder
from kiota_abstractions.api_error import APIError
import asyncio
class Graph:
    settings: SectionProxy
    client_credential: ClientSecretCredential
    adapter: GraphRequestAdapter
    app_client: GraphServiceClient

    def __init__(self, config: SectionProxy):
        self.settings = config
        client_id = self.settings['clientId']
        tenant_id = self.settings['tenantId']
        client_secret = self.settings['clientSecret']

        self.client_credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
        auth_provider = AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(self.client_credential) # type: ignore
        self.adapter = GraphRequestAdapter(auth_provider)
        self.app_client = GraphServiceClient(self.adapter)

    async def get_app_only_token(self):
        graph_scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        access_token = await self.client_credential.get_token(graph_scope)
        return access_token.token
    
    async def get_users(self):
        try:
            query_params = UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
                # Only request specific properties
                select = ['displayName', 'id', 'mail'],
                # Get at most 25 results
                top = 25,
                # Sort by display name
                orderby= ['displayName']
            )
            request_config = UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
                query_parameters=query_params
            )

            users = await self.app_client.users.get(request_configuration=request_config)
            return users
        except APIError as e:
            print(f'Error: {e.error.message}')
            

    async def me(self):
        try:
            me = await self.app_client.me.get()
            if me:
                print(me)
        except APIError as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
```

---

### ****Output****

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAf8h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I took reference from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python-app-only?tabs=aad.
> Copied and pasted the exact code but it is not returning list of users. It is returning access token though.

I tried with same document in my environment and even for me it is not listing users, it returns access token though.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the below code to get the list of users using Python.

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json


tenant_id=""
client_id=""
client_secret=""

token_endpoint = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token" 
data = {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "client_id": f"{client_id}",  
      "client_secret": f"{client_secret}",  
      "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    }
response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=data)
access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
# print("Access Token:", access_token)

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the request to the API endpoint
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the response JSON
users = json.loads(response.text)
# Print the list of users
for user in users["value"]:
    print("List of Users:")
    print(user["displayName"])
```

**Output:**

```
List of Users:
MOD xxxr
Alex xxxx
Allan xxx
Demo Kxxxx
Demo xxxx1
Demo xxxxr
Dexx
Diego xxxxx
emovaya
employee
evenyxxxxx
Exchangexxxx
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Venkatesan ! The alternative code works.